# Looking for a short story from the '80s where inanimate objects talk because of a fluke

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, powers

Looking for a short story a friend of a friend described. I Googled around but can't find it. Anyone know this one?

"This is reminding me of a funny short-short SF story that I can't find from a magazine in the '80s, in which voices and inanimate things start talking to this guy and he starts to develop strange powers, only what's actually going on (as the voices helpfully explain) is just a series of incredibly improbable random events. At one point one of the voices flubs a word, and then explains, "It's hard to get all the words right when all of this is just a fluke."

"It was very clever. At the end, the guy asks if the forces of randomness can give him wings, and it starts to happen, but then his body suddenly disintegrates into dust, which randomly settles on the floor in a pattern that spells out, 'OOPS.'"

"It was in Asimov's or F&SF, probably in the mid-'80s."

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is "[The Random Man](http://www.marclaidlaw.com/online-fiction/the-random-man/)" by Marc Laidlaw.

> “No particular reason, it’s yust happening. Given a random universe, it’s perfectly plausible, though the florts are against it.”
>
> “The whats?”
>
> “I meant ‘odds.’ It’s hard to get all the words right when everything is just a fluke.”

....

> “Sure,” said Milt. “Why not? If I’ve been chosen at random, why not?” He paused. “Say, does that mean I can do anything?”
>
> SURE. The chrome letters on the Westinghouse this time.
>
> “Fly?”
>
> Milt felt a rippling in his shoulders. Huge wings unfolded from his back. He spread them across  the living room.
>
> “Wow. And big muscles?”
>
> Milt felt himself growing larger, swelling . . . suddenly there was an odd twisting amid his molecular components. A scattering.
>
> THE ODDZ WERE AGAINST IT, the silverware opined.
>
> Milt was gone, spreading in a fine dust of randomly scattered particles. The cloud eddied about a bit, flowed over couch and coffee table, drifted at last onto the floor. Its last random drifting said:
>
> OOPZ

A search for `"hard to get all the words right"` on Google Books brought up an image of an excerpt from *[Isaac Asimov's Science Fiction Magazine, Volume 8](https://books.google.com/books?id=sNhaAAAAYAAJ&q=%22hard%20to%20get%20all%20the%20words%20right%22&dq=%22hard%20to%20get%20all%20the%20words%20right%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjt3baUxs3XAhUMTSYKHdxFDe0Q6AEINDAC)*. Using the longer quote, I searched for `"I meant 'odds.' It's hard to get all the words right"` and came upon Mr. Laidlaw's site, and an [Internet Archive copy of the magazine](https://archive.org/details/Asimovs_v08n07_1984-07).

Comment: @Goblortikus: Providing a specific enough quote like that helped immensely.

Comment: I think I had that issue.  I used your link, and the Editorial is haunting — he describes his bypass surgery, where, unbeknownst to him, he was mortally infected with tainted donor blood

Comment: @JDługosz: Something which wasn't revealed properly until after his death, of course, due to the stigma against HIV and how people generally assumed it was acquired. The tainted blood scandal continues to rock the donation world today. One bad test and you're banned for life, even if the test is proven a false positive. Be a man and have sex with one man, and you're banned for life (although that one is softening). They can't be too careful.